# accessing a dataset and table adapter from a new class

Tags: c#, database

I created a working Windows Forms project in C# that accesses an Access database of recipes. Using table adapters and the dataset I am able to query, update and insert new data into the database.

I created a new VS project, imported my database and started a new class. My problem is when I try to set up the table adapters I get errors, specifically with the `.Fill()` method. When I check the datasource.xsd I can see that the `.get()` and `.Fill()` methods were created but I can't seem to access them like I did when I just dragged and dropped the binding source onto the WinForm previously.

I copied the code to programmatically create the table adapters from the MSDN website but I get the error on the line where I call `ingredientTableAdapter.Fill(recipiesNewDataSet);` method. Any one have a clue why? Here's my code on this project so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyRecipeDataBase
{

    class QueryClass

    {

        recipiesNewDataSet recipiesNewDataSet = new recipiesNewDataSet();

        recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter ingredientTableAdapter = new recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter();

        ingredientTableAdapter.Fill(recipiesNewDataSet);



    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: it says specifically that ingredientTableAdapter is a field but used as a type where I try to call the .Fill() method.

Comment: sorry it looks like part of my post didn't take. I've already created a working project using these methods, but I wanted to create some separation of code. Dragging and dropping binding sources onto the windows form creates the table adapters for you. Here I'm trying to create it in a separate class where I will send the info from the ui to this class to run a query or update the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face!

You're putting code directly in the `class` body. It should be inside a `function`. Inside the class constructor, for instance.

```
class QueryClass
{
    public QueryClass()
    {
    recipiesNewDataSet recipiesNewDataSet = new recipiesNewDataSet();

    recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter ingredientTableAdapter = new recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter();

    ingredientTableAdapter.Fill(recipiesNewDataSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, thanks for the help!! I couldn't understand why it wouldn't take what I knew to be right.

Comment: tried to vote you up but I don't have enough points, but really, thanks again!

Comment: @CraigSmith - That's Ok. Just accept the answer if you can. And I was glad to help :)